# PHP error - "There is no disk in the drive"

Tags: php, windows, dependency-management

How come when I run `php` from the command prompt I get a message from php.exe saying "There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive F:." What does drive F have to do with anything?!

I can still do PHP commands, but it sure is annoying to have that message pop up whenever I run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found it is an unresolved bug in PHP https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68312 and some people just remap their F: drive to something else, which I did with these instructions that I found:

> Run regedit and find the following key.
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices
> Right-click "\DosDevices\G:" and then click Rename.
> Rename it to "\DosDevices\M:" or your preferred letter. 
> Restart your computer and remap your drive.
> ```

UPDATE:

Better solution from that same linked page: just create an environment variable called "OPENSSL_CONF" with a value of "C:\". Some bug having to do with OpenSSL. It just needs a path that exists to point to to stop the error. I don't think it matters what the path is as long as it isn't something unreliable like a removable media drive.

Comment: Reading you gave me an idea. I just inserted a disk in F: drive and the pop up "There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive F"  stopped appearing on typing commands, even after removing the disk. Looks really stupid but worked as it.

Answer (score 0):

I just logged off Windows and logged back on and the message has gone.

Answer (score 0):

The "VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe" for php 5.4 worked for me. I only had to take the root files of the "VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe" and dump them in the phpdesktop-chrome/php/ directory. Because the php.ini file is renamed to put it into production all of your settings stay intact. Thanks Mohamed.

Answer (score -1):

Go to http://windows.php.net/download/ and:

For PHP 5.4 download "VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe" zip file
For PHP 5.6 download "VC11 x86 Non Thread Safe" zip file
Extract it and put binaries in phpdesktop-chrome/php/ directory.

Comment: Could you explain the problem or why this is a solution?

Comment: Tried both 5.6.27 and 7.0.12 and neither versions fixed the issue :(

Note that a Windows reboot will clear the issue. Inserting USB and removing it, then running php app that looks at disk drives causes the issue to reoccur every time.